# Django REST API pagination: always return the same data

Tags: python, django, api, rest, pagination

Based on this [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination),
I tried to paginate a list, but failed.

### Code:

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def test(request):
    objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
    paginator = Paginator(objects, 2)
    page = paginator.page(1)
    serializer = PaginationSerializer(instance=page, context={'request':request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^test/$', 'ptt.views.test'))
```

### Result:

```
{
    "count": 4, 
    "next": "http://localhost/test/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        "john", 
        "paul"
    ]
}
```

I was expecting to get "george" and "ringo" by visiting `http://localhost/test/?page=2`, 
but I still got "john" and "paul"... 
Why? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` is hard-coded. So the first page is fetched.

```
page = paginator.page(1)
```

Use the `page` parameter passed:

```
page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', '1')))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was passing wrong argument in query param for page no. It was `page` but I was passing `page_no`